# Rendering a gsp page after an ajax success

Tags: ajax, render, gsp

I want to render a gsp page inside a fancybox after the ajax call has returned a success.

I have done the following :

```
   function editCompanyProfile(companyProfileId){
   $.ajax({
       url: '${createLink(controller: 'benefitContract',action: 'editCompanyProfile')}',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {id:companyProfileId},
       success: function (data) {
           $.fancybox({
            /* I need to render a gsp here */
           })
       }
   })
```

}

```
     def editCompanyProfile(){
          def isroleAdministrator=false
    if (User.findById(session.userId).allAuthorities?.contains('ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')){
        isroleAdministrator=true;
    }
    render(template:"/benefitContract/companyProfile",model:[isroleAdministrator:isroleAdministrator,companyProfile:params.id])
}
```

Could anyone tell me how should i go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try overriding the div's content instead. It will be less tedious and more immaculate.

```
function editCompanyProfile(companyProfileId,groupId){
   $.ajax({
       url: '${createLink(controller: 'benefitContract',action: 'addEditCompanyProfile')}',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {sourceId:companyProfileId,groupId:groupId},
       success: function (data) {
           $('#companyProfile').html(data);
       }
   })
}
```

Comment: ...i tried as you said and it gave me the result i wanted. You are right instead of opening a new fancy-box  overriding the div's content is much more efficient..